# Rsyslog not logging after logrotate

Tags: rsyslog

I am using rsyslog and have a number of network devices sending their logs to this server. Rsyslog then splits each out device's logs into "devicename.log". Via this:

```
$template FILENAME,"/data/logs/%fromhost%.log"

*,local0,local1,local2,local3,local4,local5,local6,local7,uucp,user.*      ?FILENAME
```

I am then trying to logrotate these files.  I have the following in my logrotate.conf.

```
  /data/logs/*.log {
    daily
    create 666 root root
    rotate 30
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
      postrotate
      reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
  }
```

Except after the logrotate job runs, about half the devices logs just stop being logged too, until I manually reload syslog. It's almost like rsyslog, just doesn't save logs for half the devices until I restart rsyslog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps logrotate cannot find your `reload` command. Remove the redirection of errors and run logrotate by hand with option `-v` for messages.